# Test class is giving only 3% coverage of apex class

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, class, issue

i have a class for which have written test class as well, included all conditions in test, which are there in class. But not sure why it is giving me coverage only 3%. have done many changes in it still no luck.

class:

```
   public class MonthlyForecasts {

    public class MonthlyForecastException extends Exception {}

    static FINAL Id SupplySMARTRecordTypeOpen = '01230000000DFlH';
    static FINAL Id SupplySMARTRecordTypeClosed = '01230000000DkkD';

    public static boolean alreadyUpdated = false;

    public static void modifyMonthlyForecasts(List<Opportunity> oppsToHaveMFsModified) {
        if(!alreadyUpdated) {
            deleteMonthlyForecasts(oppsToHaveMFsModified);
            createMonthlyForecasts(oppsToHaveMFsModified);
            alreadyUpdated = true;
        }
    }

    public static void deleteMonthlyForecasts(List<Opportunity> oppsToHaveMFsDeleted) {   

        try {
            for (
                List<Monthly_Forecast__c> mFsToBeDeleted : [
                    SELECT Id
                    FROM Monthly_Forecast__c
                    WHERE Opportunity__c IN :oppsToHaveMFsDeleted
                ]
            )
                delete mFsToBeDeleted;
        } catch (Exception e) {}            
    }

    public static void createMonthlyForecasts(List<Opportunity> oppsToHaveMFsCreated) {

        FINAL Integer adderDelayInMonths = 3;
        FINAL Integer otherDelayInMonths = 1;
        FINAL Integer yearsOfRetainerMFs = 3;

        List<Monthly_Forecast__c> mFsToBeCreated = new List<Monthly_Forecast__c>();
        List<Opportunity> oppsThatMeetCriteria = new List<Opportunity>();

        oppsThatMeetCriteria = getOppsThatMeetCriteria(oppsToHaveMFsCreated);

        for (Opportunity opp: oppsThatMeetCriteria) {

            Date mFStartDate = NULL;
            Date mFEndDate = NULL;
            Date payStartDate = NULL;
            Date payEndDate = NULL;
            Date retainerStartDate = NULL;

            Monthly_Forecast__c newMF = NULL;

            if (opp.EPS_Payment_Format__c == 'Retainer') {

                 if (opp.Effective_Date__c != NULL)
                     retainerStartDate = opp.Effective_Date__c;
                 else
                     retainerStartDate = opp.CloseDate;

                payStartDate = retainerStartDate.addMonths(otherDelayInMonths);

                if (opp.Termination_Date__c != NULL)
                    payEndDate = opp.Termination_Date__c.addMonths(otherDelayInMonths);
                else
                    payEndDate = payStartDate.addYears(yearsOfRetainerMFs).addDays(-1);
            }
            else if (opp.EPS_Payment_Format__c == 'Adder') {
                payStartDate = opp.Effective_Date__c.addMonths(adderDelayInMonths);
                payEndDate = opp.Termination_Date__c.addMonths(adderDelayInMonths);
            }
            else if (opp.EPS_Payment_Format__c == 'One-Time Fee') {
                payStartDate = opp.Effective_Date__c.addMonths(otherDelayInMonths);
                payEndDate = opp.Termination_Date__c.addMonths(otherDelayInMonths);
            }
            mFStartDate = payStartDate;
            do {
                if (mFStartDate.toStartOfMonth().addMonths(1) > payEndDate)
                    mFEndDate = payEndDate;
                else
                    mFEndDate = mFStartDate.toStartOfMonth().addMonths(1).addDays(-1);
                newMF = new Monthly_Forecast__c (
                    Opportunity__c = opp.Id,
                    Period_Start_Date__c = mFStartDate,
                    Period_End_Date__c = mFEndDate);
                mFsToBeCreated.add(newMF);
                if (payEndDate > mFEndDate)
                    mFStartDate = mFEndDate.addDays(1);
            } while (payEndDate > mFEndDate);
            if (1000 - mFsToBeCreated.size() < 49) {
                insert mFsToBeCreated;
                mFsToBeCreated = new List<Monthly_Forecast__c>();
            }            
        }
        if (mFsToBeCreated.size() > 0)
            insert mFsToBeCreated;
    }

    public static List<Opportunity> getOppsThatMeetCriteria(List<Opportunity> oppsToHaveMFsCreated) {

        List<Opportunity> oppsThatMeetCriteria = new List<Opportunity>();

        for (Opportunity opp : oppsToHaveMFsCreated) {
            if (
                (
                    opp.RecordTypeId == SupplySMARTRecordTypeOpen ||  
                    opp.RecordTypeId == SupplySMARTRecordTypeClosed
                )
                &&  opp.StageName != NULL
                &&  opp.StageName != '7-Qualified Out'
                &&  opp.StageName != '7-Lost'
                &&  
                (
                    (
                        opp.EPS_Payment_Format__c == 'Retainer' &&  
                        (
                            opp.CloseDate != NULL ||  
                            opp.Effective_Date__c != NULL
                        ) && 
                        opp.EPS_Monthly_Retainer_Payment__c != NULL
                    )
                    ||  
                    (
                        opp.EPS_Payment_Format__c == 'Adder' &&  
                        opp.Effective_Date__c != NULL &&  
                        opp.Termination_Date__c != NULL
                    )
                    ||  
                    (
                        opp.EPS_Payment_Format__c == 'One-Time Fee' &&  
                        opp.Solution_Fee__c != NULL &&  
                        opp.Effective_Date__c != NULL &&  
                        opp.Termination_Date__c != NULL
                    )
                )
            )
            oppsThatMeetCriteria.add(opp);
        }        
        return oppsThatMeetCriteria;            
    }
}
```

test :

```
    @isTest
private class MonthlyForecastsTest {

    static Date firstPeriod = NULL;
    static Double forecastAmtSum = 0;
    static List<Monthly_Forecast__c> mFs= new List<Monthly_Forecast__c>();

    static testMethod void validateMFTrigger() {

        //Create test Account
        Account acct = new Account(
            Name = 'Test Account',
            Type = 'Other'
        );
        insert acct;

        //Create new Opportunity
        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(
            Name = 'Test Opp',
            RecordTypeId = '01230000000DFlH',
            AccountId = acct.id,
            CloseDate = date.newInstance(2009,5,1),
            StageName = '4-Propose',
            LeadSource = 'Existing Customer',
            Effective_Date__c = date.newInstance(2009,5,18),
            Termination_Date__c = date.newInstance(2010,5,17),
            EPS_Annual_Energy_Amount__c = 1445000,
            EPS_Margin__c = 0.0015,
            EPS_Payment_Format__c = 'Adder'
        );
        insert opp;
        opp.EPS_Margin__c = 0.0015;
        update opp; 
        setTestVariables(opp);

        opp.EPS_Payment_Format__c = 'Retainer';
        MonthlyForecasts.alreadyUpdated = false;
        update opp;
        setTestVariables(opp);    

        //Make sure CloseDate is used as payStartDate if Contract Effective Date is NULL
        opp.EPS_Payment_Format__c = 'Retainer';
        opp.Effective_Date__c = NULL;
        MonthlyForecasts.alreadyUpdated = false;
        update opp;
        setTestVariables(opp);

        RecordType rt = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE Name = 'SupplySMART - Closed'];
        opp.RecordTypeId = rt.Id;
        opp.Effective_Date__c = date.newInstance(2009,5,18);
        MonthlyForecasts.alreadyUpdated = false;          
        update opp;
        setTestVariables(opp); 

        //Make sure correct 3 yrs of MFs generated if "Contract Termination Date" is NULL
        opp.Termination_Date__c = NULL;
        MonthlyForecasts.alreadyUpdated = false;          
        update opp;
        setTestVariables(opp); 

        delete opp;
        delete acct;
    }

    static testMethod void validateMFTrigger2() {
        //Create test Account
        Account acct = new Account(
            Name = 'Test Account',
            Type = 'Other'
        );
        insert acct;

        //Create new Opportunity
        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(
            Name = 'Test Opp',
            RecordTypeId = '01230000000DFlH',
            AccountId = acct.id,
            CloseDate = date.newInstance(2009,5,1),
            StageName = '4-Propose',
            LeadSource = 'Existing Customer',
            Effective_Date__c = date.newInstance(2009,5,18),
            Termination_Date__c = date.newInstance(2010,5,17),
            EPS_Annual_Energy_Amount__c = 1445000,
            EPS_Margin__c = 0.0015,
            EPS_Payment_Format__c = 'Adder'
        );
        insert opp;

        OpportunityHandler.resetTriggeredIds();
        opp.EPS_Payment_Format__c = 'Adder';
        MonthlyForecasts.alreadyUpdated = false;
        update opp;
        setTestVariables(opp);

        OpportunityHandler.resetTriggeredIds();
        opp.EPS_Payment_Format__c = 'One-Time Fee';
        MonthlyForecasts.alreadyUpdated = false;
        update opp;
        setTestVariables(opp);

        OpportunityHandler.resetTriggeredIds();
        opp.Amount = 5000;
        opp.Termination_Date__c = date.newInstance(2009,06,30);
        MonthlyForecasts.alreadyUpdated = false;          
        update opp;
        setTestVariables(opp);
        //This is valued at 40% b/c it's in Stage 2
        /*Forecast estimate could be off by up to 11% (in worst-case, unusual scenario)
          in either direction
          due to fact that MF estimates are calculated on a daily basis, and are offset by
          1 full month, not by a set number of days.
          For example, if original contract was only one month long and ran from 2/1-2/28 in
          a non-leap-year instance of February, then MF would be offset and would run for full length
          of March.  Since March has 31 days while non-leap-year Feb has only 28, the MF would
          be overestimated by (31-28)/28, or about 10.7%.
        */
    }

    static testMethod void validateMFTrigger3() {
        //Create test Account
        Account acct = new Account(
            Name = 'Test Account',
            Type = 'Other'
        );
        insert acct;

        //Create new Opportunity
        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(
            Name = 'Test Opp',
            RecordTypeId = '01230000000DFlH',
            AccountId = acct.id,
            CloseDate = date.newInstance(2009,5,1),
            StageName = '4-Propose',
            LeadSource = 'Existing Customer',
            Effective_Date__c = date.newInstance(2009,5,18),
            Termination_Date__c = date.newInstance(2010,5,17),
            EPS_Annual_Energy_Amount__c = 1445000,
            EPS_Margin__c = 0.0015,
            EPS_Payment_Format__c = 'Adder'
        );
        insert opp;

        opp.Amount = 7000;
        MonthlyForecasts.alreadyUpdated = false;          
        update opp;
        setTestVariables(opp);

        opp.Termination_Date__c = date.newInstance(2011,06,30);
        MonthlyForecasts.alreadyUpdated = false;          
        update opp;
        setTestVariables(opp);

         //Test extreme date case
        opp.Effective_Date__c = date.newInstance(2009,01,01);
        opp.Termination_Date__c = date.newInstance(2009,01,31);
        opp.StageName = '7-Won';
        MonthlyForecasts.alreadyUpdated = false;          
        update opp;
        setTestVariables(opp);

        MonthlyForecasts.alreadyUpdated = false;
    }

    private static void setTestVariables(Opportunity opp) {

        firstPeriod = NULL;
        forecastAmtSum = 0;
        mFs = NULL; 

        mFs = [SELECT Id, Forecast_Amount__c, Opportunity__c, Period_Start_Date__c FROM Monthly_Forecast__c WHERE Opportunity__c = :opp.Id];

        for (Monthly_Forecast__c mF : mFs) {
            if (firstPeriod == NULL || firstPeriod > mF.Period_Start_Date__c)
                firstPeriod = mF.Period_Start_Date__c;
            forecastAmtSum += mF.Forecast_Amount__c;
        }    
    }
}
```

I have include every possible line in test with unique data and which should cover all logic part in apex class. but it is not doing so, I tried to find out the cause, didn't succeed in that as well. hence asking for help.

Comment: hey Phil.. thanks for sharing link. Yes i have gone through every possible article I find to make sure about issue, but didnt find anything.

Comment: Do you have a trigger that passes info to this apex class? I don't see you calling your apex class or any of its methods in your test class at all other than to set `MonthlyForecasts.alreadyUpdate = false;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are trying to (functionally) test a trigger which invokes the Methods in MonthlyForecast class. If that is the case, check if:

1. The trigger is set for (either before or after) update
2. The trigger has a static variable preventing recursive execution in which case the updates won't fire the trigger again. If that is the case, you can either add a method to re-set the control variable or add a bypass for Testing.

If instead of functional testing for the trigger —we are assuming you have—, you just want to Unit Test MonthlyForecasts; you can directly invoke its methods in your test as in `MonthlyForecasts.modifyMonthlyForecasts(new List<Opportunity>{opp});`.

Another general consideration:
To get a better understanding of the lines you are not covering you can run your Test Class in the Dev Console and then look for the lines highlighted in red on your Functional Class.